# How can I get rid of Jarate?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In what ways can I get rid of Jarate? It seems to be quite annoying when I get hit by one; I end up dying very quickly because enemies do a ton of damage to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instant Removal

- Resupply cabinet
- Going underwater
- Ubercharges (it clears effects like jarate, fire, milk on the target)

Expedited Removal

- Standing by a dispenser for a while
- Getting healed by a medic over time

Answer (score 2):

Getting healed by a medic or a dispenser removes Jarate very quickly, according to the [TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Jarate).

Unconfirmed accounts suggest jumping into water also 'rinses it off' ;)

Comment: Jumping into water will remove it quickly.

Comment: Completely submersing yourself in water instantly removes it, but a puddle will do nothing.