# Does Jarate apply to enemies under an Ubercharge?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-sniper

I was curious if Jarate covers enemies who are under Ubercharge. Has anyone done some experimentation with this and if so, does this also apply to the other 3 Mediguns' Ubers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  Ubered players are not affected by status effects. Note that this *only* works with the stock Ubercharge.

In fact, flashing someone with a stock Medigun's Ubercharge will clear all status effects currently on them.  Just be aware that the amount of time on the Uber goes down every time you change targets, to a minimum of 2.666 seconds (from the normal 8 seconds) for 5 or more targets.

Note that this **also** only works with the stock Ubercharge.

Having said that, all Mediguns will shorten the duration of the fire, Jarate, and bleed status effects simply by healing said person.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me know who to splash and who not to.

Comment: Healing someone shortens the duration of Jarate? That's news to me.

Comment: @Zibbobz It's not widely known, but it's definitely something I've noticed while playing.  If you jarate a Medic and his target, the jarate effect on the target is noticeably shorter than the jarate effect on the Medic.  I want to say it shortens the effect by half.

Comment: This answer http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/93469/55285 seems to confirm your theory, so well done on remembering it so well. :)